Should research statements be renamed to match each university's specific terminology?
I'm preparing applications for multiple universities, and I've noticed variations in the terminology used for research-related documents. Some universities request a "statement of research," while others ask for a "research plan."
In the cover letter, e.g.,
What do I need to include in a tenure-track assistant professor job application cover letter?

Enclosed are my curriculum vitae, teaching and research statements.

However, I'm unsure if I should adjust this wording to match the exact terminology used in each university's announcement.
Considering the time investment, if I spend 10 minutes renaming documents (including teaching and the extra time to double check) for each application, it would amount to about 9 hours for 50 universities.

9 hours for a permanent job search is too much for you? Well, apply to fewer places I suppose. Seems a good investment for the next 30-40 years of your career though.

@JonCuster for this kind of thing, I would say yes. But I appreciate your suggestion on applying fewer places.

I would assume this would be a drop in the bucket compared to all the other customizing you're doing for a particular application. Right?

While it’s normal to apply to multiple tenure positions as one gets rejected from the first few, applying to 50 positions at once and expecting less than 10 minutes effort each seems very unusual. Tenure track isn’t about fire and forget applications.

Minor frame challenge: it isn't necessary to put something like "Enclosed are (list of the documents you require)" in the cover letter in the first place. If the documents are in the package they will be seen anyway. Sure, if your application is incomplete, perhaps such a boilerplate message would make the committee slightly more likely to reach out. But, assuming you double check that the application actually is complete before submitting, there really doesn't seem to be much utility there. (It could change if you attach and want to describe a nonstandard document, but I assume that isn't the case here.) Why not remove this sentence that communicates nothing that isn't expected and instead spending that space on an extra sentence focused on setting your application apart from the rest or emphasizing your fit for the position?
Customizing cover letters is worthwhile, but the effort is better spent on writing something meaningful than on dealing with specific phrasing of boilerplate sentences. That said, personally, I would change the heading of the research statement to "statement of research" (that is, in the actual document), etc. when appropriate. Doing this only at the end while double checking that have provided all documents asked for in the job description could minimize the overhead.

Ideally, you should not just be renaming the documents but customising the statements for each application. The easier you make it for each selection committee to see that you are a good fit for the particular gap that they are trying to fill at their particular university, the better your results are likely to be. The more you make them work to compare your CV and statement to their needs, the less likely they are to see you as a good fit.
Submitting the same application materials to every opening makes it easy for you to apply for many positions, but it means that you are not showing yourself to your best advantage for any of them.
My perspective is shaped by the way we do things here in Australia: instead of asking for teaching and research statements, each job advertisement lists its own set of "essential" and "desirable" selection criteria and applicants who do not write a response to each criterion as written will usually not be considered at all. I know that is not how things are done in the US and might seem like a lot of work; nonetheless, if I were applying for a job in the US, I'd read each advertisement carefully to figure out what they are really looking for and tailor my cover letter and research and teaching statements to explicitly address those implicit criteria.

This is highly dependent on the position for which you're applying.
I'm a math professor at a mid-tier R1 university in the US. From the standpoint of our tenure-track hiring, I'd say... it doesn't matter. Indeed, we expect (and see) very little in the way of customization of application materials. I'd expect the same is mostly true at similar departments.
But I chatted with a math professor at a small liberal arts college, also in the US, and learned just how different things are there. He said that he considers the cover letter the most important part of the application! Also, he recommended that the research statement itself be customized -- if I recall correctly, he recommended a shorter statement (around three pages), readable to someone well outside your field. I don't think he expects the research statement to be customized to his own institution in particular, but you wouldn't want to use the same research statement as for an R1.
Bottom line? Seek out advice from people at departments similar to where you're applying. Your question can't reliably be answered in the generality you've asked it.
